# HASKELL: In trouble with function to parse from an input String to my DataType

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, io

I got some really helpful tips in a question related to this Project before, but now, I need help with the following. I have a datatype (same as in previous question):

```
type Var = String
data FProp = V Var
           | No FProp
           | Y FProp FProp
           | O FProp FProp
           | Si FProp FProp
           | Sii FProp FProp
           deriving Read
```

And I need to parse an input string from the user into my datatype. I finally built the function:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome! Choose your option."
    a <- getLine
    if (a Prelude.== "(1)")
        then do
            y <- getLine
            let ys = read (y)::String
                     in let f = parseStringToFProp ys
                     in let b = determinarTautologia f
                     in printResult b
    else do
        y <- getLine
        x <- getLine
        let {ys = read (y)::String; xs = read (x)::String}
             in let {f1 = parseStringToFProp ys; f2 = parseStringToFProp xs}
             in let b = sonEquivalentes f1 f2
             in printResult b
```

this is the code for the function which calls the parser, which is my main doubt:

```
f:: [Char] -> FProp
f (x:xs) | x == ' '= f xs                            
         | x == '(' || x == ')' = f xs                   
         | x == 'S' && head xs Prelude.== 'i' 
           && head (tail xs) == 'i' = (Sii (f xs))
         | x == 'S' && head xs == 'i' 
           && not (head (tail xs) == 'i') = (Si (f xs)) 
         | x == 'Y' = (Y (f xs))
         | x == 'O' = (O (f xs))
         | x == 'N' && head xs == 'o' = (O (f xs))
```

The function aims to create an FProp from a String, being its type `[Char] -> FProp`. The problem is that I do not come up with the base case of this recursive function. What could I do if I get `[]`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I attempted to apply simple formatting, but there are some newlines and indentation missing from `parseStringToFProp`, at least.

Comment: One of your lines is literally over 330 characters.  Please format your code to fit in a normal window.

Comment: You should avoid all those `==,head,tail,null` and exploit pattern matching instead. This would greatly improve readability, and avoid partial functions which can crash your program. E.g. `foo [] = ... ; foo ('S':'i':xs) = ...`

Comment: Yes, You're definitely right, I just fixed the code.But my doubt is: what should I do in case I get the empty string or [ ] ?

Comment: After more pondering, I think the above code can not be easily fixed into a working version. If you need to parse parenthesized expressions, precedence, etc. you need to use a proper parser, define (e.g.) a LL(1) grammar, and so on. You could exploit the `parsec` library which is quite popular, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

With the read function you dont need parse anymore just write the datatype in your input as you have declared before in the data constructor even with parentheses, for example: `No (V “some string”)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to choose any input format, and if it is acceptable for the user to enter expressions like:

```
(Si (V "q") (No (V "p")))
```

quotation marks and all, then there is a very simple solution.

You can have Haskell derive a `Read` instance for your data type by adding `deriving (Read)` at the end of your definition.  You have already done this, but you possibly haven't realized that the effect of this is to **automatically** define a parser for your data type, which can be used via `read`, `reads`, and some related functions.

For example, if you compile and run the following standalone program:

```
type Var = String
data FProp = V Var
           | No FProp
           | Y FProp FProp
           | O FProp FProp
           | Si FProp FProp
           | Sii FProp FProp
           deriving (Show, Read)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter an expression:"
  str <- getLine
  let fprop = read str :: FProp
  putStrLn "Your expression was:"
  print fprop
```

this will automatically parse a user-supplied string into an `FProp` (and just print it back out, but you can do anything you like with `fprop` in your real program):

```
$ runghc Proposition.hs
Enter an expression:
(Si (V "q") (No (V "p")))
Your expression was:
Si (V "q") (No (V "p"))
$
```

This program isn't very robust.  If you enter an invalid expression, it'll generate an exception.  You can use `reads` instead to make it more user-friendly:

```
getFExpr :: IO FProp
getFExpr = do
  putStrLn "Enter an FProp expression:"
  str <- getLine
  case reads str of
    (x, ""):_ -> return x
    _         -> putStrLn "\nInvalid expression!\n" >> getFExpr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fprop <- getFExpr
  putStrLn "Your expression was:"
  print fprop
```